# Convert in-document links of an HTML page

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, conversion, html

Is there a way to convert in-document links (#anchor) in an HTML file to in-document links in a Microsoft Word file when converting the HTML to DOCX?

When converting an HTML file to a DOCX document, all the links stay intact, but the in-document links then refer to the HTML document on the server where the document was originally located. I would like those links to be converted to in-document links in my DOCX file, so that when clicking the link, the focus jumps to the referred position within the converted DOCX file.
Is that possible? If so, how?

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Linux: Download the HTML with `wget --convert-links ...` - the links within the HTML will be converted so that they are "local". On MS OS? Use either cygwin or that subsystem to run Linux to get acccess to `wget`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But the links are just converted to have the new directory name of the downloaded files. They still are full links instead of local links. When moving the file to another directory, the links to not work anymore. Also, when creating a DOCX file (and afterwards an epub file) from the document, the links are broken.